# Android L setEnterTransition not working

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, transition

I'm currently trying to use the new transition animations in Android 5.0.
I started as suggested by many Tutorials:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Explode());
    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Java Skill");
    getActionBar().setElevation(2);
}
```

I put this code into every activity of my project but it never works. The only animation I get is the "slide in effect" from the bottom.
Am I doing something wrong here? Do I have to define anything else, maybe in my layouts or styles.xml?

I hope anyone ran into the same problem as me. Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation may be wrong. You need to enable FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly this didn't do anything to the problem. I changed it in every activity from my app but the animations still won't show up. Is there maybe anything i have to define in the layouts of my activities?

Comment: Did you start the activity using ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation?

Comment: Thank you very much! Animations are now finally working. Maybe this step should be mentioned in the documentation.